# Manually or Explicitly indexing a folder in Thunderbird with Gloda GlodaIndexer

Tags: javascript, html, indexing, thunderbird-addon

1) Open a new tab with the

```
document.getElementById("tabmail").openTab("chromeTab", {
    chromePage: “indexWithGloda.html”,
});
```

2) The file `indexWithGloda.html` has a button with an onlick even that should start the indexing.

```
function onClickStartIndexingWithGloda()
{
    var inboxFolder = getInboxFolder(); // Find the inbox folder
    GlodaMsgIndexer.indexFolder(inboxFolder, ["force"]);
    var job = GlodaIndexer._indexQueue.pop();
    GlodaMsgIndexer._worker_folderIndex(job);
}

// Adding a messenger lazy getter to the MailServices even though it's not a service
XPCOMUtils.defineLazyGetter(MailServices, "messenger", function () {
    return Cc["@mozilla.org/messenger;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIMessenger);
});

function getInboxFolder() {
    var inbox = null;
    var accounts = [x for each (x in fixIterator(MailServices.accounts.accounts, Ci.nsIMsgAccount))].filter(function (x) x.incomingServer);

    var server = accounts[0].incomingServer;
    var folder = server.rootFolder;

    var searchForInbox = function(folder) {
        var isInbox = folder.getFlag(Ci.nsMsgFolderFlags.Inbox);
        if (isInbox) {
            inbox = folder;
        }
        else if (folder.hasSubFolders) {
            for each (var subFolder in fixIterator(folder.subFolders, Ci.nsIMsgFolder))
                searchForInbox(subFolder);
        }
    }
    searchForInbox(folder);
    return inbox;
}
```

The problem is that the call `GlodaMsgIndexer._worker_folderIndex(job);` in function `onClickStartIndexingWithGloda()` does not really start the indexing. I guess it should be called in some asynchronous manner but I do not know how to start it asynchronously. I would very much appreciate any help here. One more question, would this method work if the folder is already indexed? If not, what is necessary to do to re-index an already indexed folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a folder is indexed or not depends on:

- the user's global preference (mailnews.database.global.indexer.enabled)
- the per-folder preferences that are accessible by right-clicking a folder, then hitting properties, and selecting "include this folder in global search results".

So I don't think you should force Gloda into indexing a folder: Gloda is able to automatically figure whenever messages are added to a folder, and index them accordingly.

Could you please tell me a little bit more about what it is that you're trying to achieve?

*Edit*: the links you're looking for are probably

- http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/db/gloda/test/unit/test_index_sweep_folder.js
- https://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/db/gloda/test/unit/resources/glodaTestHelper.js

Comment: I am preparing a demo/experiment and need to have a way to make Gloda index a specific folder at a specific moment - when I press a button. I need the indexing to be under manual control so that I can show how the progress of the indexing goes.

Comment: In that case, you completely want to short-circuit the gloda indexing logic. I suggest you take a look at the testing framework we have in-tree, and see how to switch gloda to "test mode", where it won't try to be smart and figure things out by itself. You should then be able to tell it manually to run a "folder indexing sweep" (that's the things you need to grep for in the source).

Comment: I've added the links as part of my earlier answer.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for the pointers. I actually was looking at these two files which you gave me as links. I the example code which I have is derived from test_index_sweep_floder.js but I did not managed to get it work - simply the call to GlodaMsgIndexer._worker_folderIndex(job); does not work because there are asyn calls inside it. Probably this is because gloda is no in test-mode. I will check how to switch gloda to test-mode.

Comment: Yes, gloda tests are run inside a test framework which uses ECMAScript 6 Iterators / Generators to perform asynchronous calls. But why is the call to `indexFolder` not enough? http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/db/gloda/modules/index_msg.js#1952

Comment: https://github.com/protz/GMail-Conversation-View/blob/master/modules/misc.js#L259 that function which I wrote will definitely reindex a set of messages, so in case nothing else works, just schedule a reindexing of all the messages in the folder. I'm using that as part of the setup assistant for Thunderbird Conversations.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! I will immediately try your last suggestion! BTW, I am not exactly sure why the call to indexFolder does not work. What I guess happens is that the call to indexFolder creates and queues a job. However, later this job is not executed/processed. That is why I try to execute it explicitly by _worker_folderIndex but this does not work either.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks a lot. Your last suggestions with the `reindexMessages` which calls `GlodaMsgIndexer.indexMessages` worked. I will post my example code for the other (future) troubled folks like me.